# How to lock a stored procedure without cancelling the new call

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that is called from a job every minute but also It can be called anytime outside the job.

The problem comes out if I called the stored procedure at the same time the job called it.

What I need is to make the second call wait until the first finish then the second call start.

I followed this [Link](http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-prevent-stored-procedure-running-concurrently-in-sql-server/) to use sp_getapplock.

Note: I tried sp_getapplock but it cancels the second call.

Update:
  This is a sample of what I'm using

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TestingLocking
AS  
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    DECLARE @returnCode INT, @DriverID INT, @OrderID int, @CarTypeID int

    EXEC @returnCode = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = 'TestingLocking',
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Session',
            @LockTimeout = 5,
            @DbPrincipal  = 'public'

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT top 5 OrderID, CarTypeID FROM Orders

    OPEN db_cursor   
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @OrderID, @CarTypeID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        --Update Orders Set DriverID = @DriverID WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
        --INSERT INTO Logs(OrderID,DriverID) Values(@OrderID,@DriverID)

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @OrderID, @CarTypeID
    END
    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor

    EXEC @returnCode = sp_releaseapplock
                        @Resource = 'TestingLocking',                       
                        @LockOwner = 'Session',
                        @DbPrincipal  = 'public'

END
GO
```

When I execute the stored from two instances of SSMS, the second one raise an error

> Cannot release the application lock (Database Principal: 'public',
>   Resource: 'TestingLocking') because it is not currently held.

Comment: You cannot *lock* a stored procedure in SQL Server - you can only place locks on the underlying **tables** in your database

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Sound like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ... You might set some kind of flag value which is set to `SP_is_running=1` in the beginning and to `=0` when you leave it again. This flag you can check in the first line `IF SP_is_running=1 RETURN;` But - to be honest - this *smells*... This is rather a question of ÌSOLATION LEVEL`...

Comment: You tried `sp_getapplock`... but how? Add details to your question please (`edit` link below your question).

Comment: @TT. I add my reference for using sp_getapplock

Comment: You'll want to perform a table lock on the top-level table.  By default, the second query will wait a set amount of time (you'll want to make sure this wait time is as short as possible to avoid deadlocks).  That being said, more information regarding the context may reveal additional options. Is this procedure a long running query?

Comment: I wasn't asking what source you used to learn about sp_getapplock, I'm asking the specific call to `sp_getapplock` you made in your Job and Stored Procedure.

Comment: @alan Actually I had to use a cursor in the stored, So it may take a long time but I don't think it will exceeds 2 or 3 seconds. It depends on users' interactivity.

Comment: Why on earth did you use a cursor? There are very few reasons why that would be necessary or good especially for something running every minute. Honestly, I suspect your problem is that the storedp roc needs work.

Comment: @HLGEM I had to use cursor and I know that it 's a disaster but really I have no other choice.

Comment: @TT. I updated the question with sample code. Can you check it please.

Comment: You have a lock timeout of ... **5 milliseconds**

Comment: @MahmoudFakhry I cannot understand why you say that you have to use a cursor and have no other choice, as you could use an Update with an Output clause. you are also using READ UNCOMMITTED which means you can read dirty data,

Comment: @MahmoudFakhry you also have no ORDER BY on your TOP 5 statement, you have no guarantee which 5 records will be returned.

Comment: @SteveFord this is just a sample code for the problem not the actual stored procedure. But I promise that I'll try Output clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified a lock timeout of 5 milliseconds, so of course the second process that tried to acquire the lock when the lock is already held, will fail almost instantly.

If you want to wait indefinitely, specify `-1` as the lock timeout. Or, specify a reasonable timeout value (remember, the parameter `@LockTimeout` is in milliseconds).

---

Second, you are not verifying the return value of the call to `sp_getapplock` after the statement `EXEC @returnCode = sp_getapplock ...`. If acquiring the lock fails then you should not release a lock. You should return from the stored procedure or job. Check the possible error codes in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx):

```
Value   Result
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0       The lock was successfully granted synchronously.
1       The lock was granted successfully after waiting for other incompatible locks to be released.
-1      The lock request timed out.
-2      The lock request was canceled.
-3      The lock request was chosen as a deadlock victim.
-999    Indicates a parameter validation or other call error.
```

Comment: Thanks man, I changed the lock timeout to -1 and it's working as expected.

Comment: (the parameter @LockTimeout is in milliseconds) nice tip.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL statement and execute the statement in one go (avoiding cursors).

How about something like this (making use of the OUTPUT clause to input into the logs table):

```
UPDATE ORDERS 
SET DriverId = O2.DriverId
OUTPUT Inserted.OrderId, Inserted.DriverId INTO Logs
FROM (SELECT Top 5 OrderId, CarTypeId, DriverId FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderId ) O2
WHERE Orders.OrderId = O2.OrderId
```

Comment: Actually I do a lot of things in the cursor like  calling external API and logging.

Comment: The SET TRANSACTION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED makes your stored procedure prone to reading (and acting on) data which is subsequently rolled back. This makes your UPDATE and INSERT statements potentially invalid. I suspect that you will end up with some data inconsistencies in your data.